# Grails console autocomplete

Tags: grails, autocomplete, console

In Grails 1.3.7, the console plugin has any autocomplete feature? 
This would be particularly interesting to people learning the language as it allows for the exploration of methods injected at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the console does not have an autocomplete feature, one thing you can do in the console to explore native and injected methods is use the `Inspect *` methods from the `Script` menu.

My personal favorite is `Inspect Last`.  You'd use it like this:

1. Create a simple program, with a trailing object:

   ```
   def foo = ""
   ```
2. Run this program (`CTRL+R` or `CMD+R`)
3. Choose `Script > Inspect Last`

It looks like this:
[image: Groovy Console Inpsector]

The reason that GroovyConsole doesn't have code completion is that while you are typing, those commands have not been run.  Therefore, there is no practical way to determine the methods on the object at that moment.  Even full-blown IDEs like IntelliJ are limited in the kinds of code completion they can offer.